# Magento order grid

Tags: magento

Hi I need to display `Order Details` grid in my Magento FRONT END page. I tried different ways, but nothing worked fine.

Also how to find `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.account.dashboard.extra') ?>` block.

Any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick way,

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app()->getStore();

echo '<pre>';
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    //->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
    ;

//echo $orders->getSelect();

//exit;

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    echo $order->getIncrementId() . ": '" . $order->getStatus() . "', " . $email . "\n";
}
```

It fetches all order details. Please comment here if you have any doubt.

Comment: Hi Elavarasan, i need to display the order grid as in the admin panel. Can't i reuse it.